# Filter a value from json array of arrays

Tags: arrays, json, filter, dataweave, mule4

This is my payload, here I need to validate the **status** field as active or inactive in `details.addressDesc` array

```
    {
    "id": "123",
    "address": [
        {
            "type": "ABC",
            "name": "name"
        }
    ],
    "details": [
        {
            "Firstname": "firstname1",
            "lastname": "lastname1",
            "addressDesc": [
                {
                    "desc": "home",
                    "status": "active"
                },
                {
                    "desc": "office",
                    "status": "inactive"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "firstname2",
            "lastname": "lastname2",
            "addressDesc": [
                {
                    "desc": "home",
                    "status": "inactive"
                },
                {
                    "desc": "office",
                    "status": "active"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "firstname3",
            "lastname": "lastname3",
            "addressDesc": [
                {
                    "desc": "home",
                    "status": "active"
                },
                {
                    "desc": "office",
                    "status": "active"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If `status is active`, corresponding `names(from details)` should be clubbed with its `desc(details.addressDesc)`
If all the elements of **status is active**, then corresponding number of **nameDetails** should be created (here firstname3 has both the status as active)

Expected Output is as below.

```
    {
    "addressDetails": [
        {
            "Firstname": "firstname1",
            "lastname": "lastname1",
            "addressName": "home",
            "status": "active"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "firstname2",
            "lastname": "lastname2",
            "addressName": "office",
            "status": "active"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "firstname3",
            "lastname": "lastname3",
            "addressName": "home",
            "status": "active"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "firstname3",
            "lastname": "lastname3",
            "addressName": "office",
            "status": "active"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this kind of problems it is easier to discompose it in steps. First get the array you are interested `payload.details` then the trick is for each element to map not the element but the nested one `addressDesc`. Using different names for the mapping operations allows to use values from the parent element. Then convert map() to flatMap() as needed or use flatten().

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json 
---
{
    addressDetails:
        payload.details flatMap ((detail, index) -> 
            detail.addressDesc 
                filter ($.status=="active")
                map {
                    Firstname: detail.Firstname,
                    lastname: detail.lastname,
                    addressName: $.desc,
                    status: $.status
                }
        )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

Here you can iterate over the details array, then iterate over the addressDesc array for each detail, and filter based on the status being "active".

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun extractDetails(details) =
    details flatMap ((detail) ->
        detail.addressDesc filter ((desc) -> desc.status == "active") map ((activeDesc) ->
            {
                Firstname: detail.Firstname,
                lastname: detail.lastname,
                addressName: activeDesc.desc,
                status: activeDesc.status
            }
        )
    )

---
{
    addressDetails: extractDetails(payload.details)
}
```